# GLFW Window Wrapper Class - Secondary Window does not close

Tags: c++, glfw

First an overview of what I am trying to achieve. The goal is to make a Windows Application using `GLFW` and `ImGui`, however before I advance any further with my project I need to make the handling of Windows more accessible.

For example, you could have a main window, and also there will be other secondary windows (such as option dialogs, about dialogs etc). Each of these child windows (which could even be modal windows etc) will likely have to be a `GLFWwindow` so that `ImGui` can draw onto them.

With a lot of help I have this code so far:

`Application.h`

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_H
#define APPLICATION_H

#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "Window.h"

class Application {
public:
    Application();
    ~Application();

    void run();

    void addWindow(Window* window, bool isMainWindow = false);

private:
    std::vector<Window*> windows;
    Window* mainWindow = nullptr;
};

#endif
```

`Application.cpp`

```
#include "Application.h"

Application::Application() {
    if (!glfwInit())
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize GLFW");
}

Application::~Application() {
    glfwTerminate();
}

void Application::run() {
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(mainWindow->getWindowHandle())) {
        for (auto window : windows) {
            window->processEvents();
            window->render();
        }
    }

    // Destroy GLFW window when the event loop exits
    glfwDestroyWindow(mainWindow->getWindowHandle());
}

void Application::addWindow(Window* window, bool isMainWindow) {
    windows.push_back(window);
    if (isMainWindow) {
        if (mainWindow != nullptr) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Main window already set");
        }
        mainWindow = window;
    }
}
```

The idea is to have a base Application class that will hold all of our created windows. We then have the base Window class:

`Window.h`

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdexcept>

class Window {
public:
    Window(int width, int height, const char* title);
    virtual ~Window();

    GLFWwindow* getWindowHandle() const;
    void processEvents();
    bool shouldClose() const;

    void render();
    virtual void close();

    virtual void runEventLoop();

    static void window_close_callback(GLFWwindow* window);

private:
    GLFWwindow* window;

protected:
    virtual void renderContent();
};

#endif
```

`Window.cpp`

```
#include "Window.h"

Window::Window(int width, int height, const char* title) {
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window) {        
        glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, this);
        glfwSetWindowCloseCallback(window, window_close_callback);
        glfwSwapInterval(1);
    }
    else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create GLFW window");
    }
}

Window::~Window() {
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
}

GLFWwindow* Window::getWindowHandle() const {
    return window;
}

void Window::processEvents() {
    glfwPollEvents();
}

bool Window::shouldClose() const {
    return glfwWindowShouldClose(window);
}

void Window::runEventLoop() {
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        processEvents();
    }
}

void Window::render() {
    if (window) {
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        renderContent();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
}

void Window::renderContent(){}

void Window::close() {
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
}

void Window::window_close_callback(GLFWwindow* window) {
    Window* instance = static_cast<Window*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window));
    if (instance != nullptr) {
        instance->close();
    }
}
```

The idea with the base Window class is it internally handles all the swapping buffers etc and will allow inherited Windows to render it's own content etc. For example, here are two Windows that inherit from the base Window:

`MainWindow.h`

```
#ifndef MAIN_WINDOW_H
#define MAIN_WINDOW_h

#include "Window.h"

class MainWindow : public Window {
public:
    MainWindow(int width, int height, const char* title);
    virtual ~MainWindow();

    virtual void close() override;

protected:
    virtual void renderContent() override;
};

#endif
```

`MainWindow.cpp`

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(int width, int height, const char* title) : Window(width, height, title) {
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
}

void MainWindow::renderContent() {
    glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void MainWindow::close() {
    printf("Closing Main Window...\n");
    Window::close();
}
```

That is the main window. We also have our secondary window, in this case AboutWindow:

`About.h`

```
#ifndef ABOUT_WINDOW_H
#define ABOUT_WINDOW_H

#include "Window.h"

class AboutWindow : public Window {
public:
    AboutWindow(int width, int height, const char* title);
    virtual ~AboutWindow();

    virtual void close() override;

protected:
    virtual void renderContent() override;
};

#endif
```

`About.cpp`

```
#include "About.h"

AboutWindow::AboutWindow(int width, int height, const char* title) : Window(width, height, title) {
}

AboutWindow::~AboutWindow() {
    printf("close me!");
}

void AboutWindow::renderContent() {

    glClearColor(0.4f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void AboutWindow::close() {
    printf("Closing About Window...\n");
    Window::close();
}
```

To finish putting it all together, the main source file:

`Main.cpp`

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "Application.h"
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "About.h"

int main() {
    Application application;

    MainWindow* mainWindow = new MainWindow(1280, 720, "Main Window");
    application.addWindow(mainWindow, true);

    AboutWindow* aboutWindow = new AboutWindow(400, 300, "About Window");
    application.addWindow(aboutWindow);

    try {
        application.run();
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
        printf("Runtime error: %s\n", e.what());
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running this will display both Windows:

[image]

Here lies the problem. As you can see from the console windows output, I had tried to close the AboutWindow with the close button, the signal was sent, but the Window never closes.

I'm thinking there's something terribly wrong with the implementation such as the way the events are polled / messages not getting received / blocked?

I can get the About Window to close by adding this:

```
void Window::close() {
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window); // adding this closes the window
}
```

However, this causes the program to crash:

[image]

So my question is, how do I solve the secondary windows closing, and is the issue much deeper such as the event loops, and if so what changes do I need to make to fix it?